# Reporting Shapiro Wilks test

Tags: anova, reporting

I'm currently writing my masters thesis, and I have used a Shapiro-Wilks test and a Levene's test prior to conducting a one way and two way ANOVA (I'm testing multiple things). I'm just wondering if I have to report the actual figures of the tests, or I can just say they where normally distributed/ equality of variances and state the more interesting results of my ANOVA.

Comment: How would a Shapiro-Wilk before ANOVA work? you'd be conducting it on the residuals from the ANOVA.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an ANOVA will answer your research question and is an appropriate model, the correct approach would be:

1. Assume that, given all structural effects, the remaining stochasticity in the response variable (i.e. the **residuals**) is normally distributed. If this assumption is not reasonable, don't use ANOVA in the first place. This also goes for other assumptions (independent observations, homoscedastic variance).
2. Fit an ANOVA type model (means per category)
3. Check for violations of the assumptions made on the **residuals**. These are the remaining values if you subtract the fitted values (means per category) from the response variable. You can use statistical tests for this, but I recommend visual diagnostics instead, as tests only give a yes or no answer.

Example in R:

```
data(iris)
Model <- aov(Sepal.Length ~ Species)
plot(Model) # visual diagnostics
Residuals <- resid(Model) # the residuals, should you want to do tests anyway
```

If you do find serious violations, perhaps the assumptions you nade were nit reasonable after all and you should consider using a different model.

In my opinion, including visual diagnostics in the appendix is a good idea as justification for your model.